# Is it possible to use imageAtomicMax on image with layout format rg32ui?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am currently using an image with layout type r32ui, but I need more bits. Is it possible to use imageAtomicMax with rg32ui? If not, is there any other way I could get more bits in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Image atomic operations can only be performed on single-channel image formats. So you can't do 64-bit atomic operations. And due to the nature of atomicity, you can't put two atomic operations next to each other and have the aggregate of them be "atomic".